# Wait for function to complete before executing next command

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a game where user writes a function that will execute and do stuff such as move a robot/rotate etc.
I've got this code :

```
  function move(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("Log 1,5");
    }, 3000);

    return true;
  }

  function anotherMove(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("Log 2,5");
    }, 2000);

    return true;
  }

  function action(){
    console.log("Log 1");
    move();
    console.log("Log 2");
    anotherMove();
    console.log("Log 3");
  }


  action();
```

Imagine move/anotherMove as robot movement and console.logs as calculations between those moves. Is there anyway to output logs correctly : 1 -> 1,5 -> 2 -> 2,5 (currently its 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1,5 -> 2,5) so basically that console.log waits for move/anotherMove to complete before executing these logs.

I can change move/anotherMove structure (it will be canvas animation) but I need action() structure stay as it is...

Thanks a lot !

Comment: To make it work the way you want, it'll freeze the page and nobody will want to play the game. Read up on asynchronous JavaScript. There are volumes of information on it.

Answer (score 1):

Promises do just what you're looking for.  These are available in ES6, or there are several libraries, for example, [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

You'll start wrapping timeout in a promise...

```
function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}
```

Now that timeout function will return a promise, which can be chained with another promise using the function `then()`.  So, for example, your `move()` function can be improved as ...

```
function move(aString, aDelay) {
    return timeout(aDelay).then( () => {
        console.log(aString);
        true;
    });
}
```

The action function almost writes itself...

```
function action() {
    console.log("Log 1");
    return move("Log 1.5", 3000).then(() => {
        console.log("Log 2");
        move("Log 2.5", 2000);
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("Log 3");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but thats exactly what I thought, I don't want to change action() function since that one will be written by user.